# Problem with map array with generics

Tags: java, arrays, generics, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java generics and array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470198/java-generics-and-array-initialization)
>   [How does one instantiate an array of maps in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493162/how-does-one-instantiate-an-array-of-maps-in-java)

I know I can do :

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

so I should be able to :

```
Map<String, Object>[] maps = new HashMap<String, Object>[10];
```

but this does not work, gives compilation problem.

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you use a `List` instead of an old fashioned array? This question has by the way been asked a lot of times before. There might be some in the *Related* secton on the right column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a quirk of generics in java. You have to declare the array like so:

```
HashMap<String, Object>[] maps = new HashMap[10];
```

later you can create each Map personally, example :

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{ 
    maps[i] = new HashMap<String,Object>();
}
```

This is a consequence of [erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure). The array is an array of `HashMap`s. The generic type param is not retained. You'll get a warning about this, but it will compile and you can suppress the warning with the `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` annotation.