# Is there a Java version of the creating an array of dictionaries like in Swift

Tags: java, swift, dictionary

In Swift I can write a dictionary like this:

```
let myDict = [
    [
        "title": "some title",
        "val": "some val",
        "url": "some url"
    ],
[
        "title": "some title",
        "val": "some val",
        "url": "some url"
    ],
]
```

Is there a android Java version of that?

Comment: It's called `Map` in Java.

Comment: @Alec OP is asking how to create an array of dictionaries

Comment: @LeoDabus my bad, edited the title

Comment: @LeoDabus a simple search, based off how to create a dictionary in java will point them in the right direction, no? If one knows how to create a map, they can surely make a map of maps. :)

Comment: @Alec yes if they know what to search

Comment: This should help you as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493162/how-does-one-instantiate-an-array-of-maps-in-java

Comment: @LeoDabus well now OP knows to search maps :D

Comment: Java doesn't have any literal syntax equivalent to Swift's. That's just the first of many pain points your bound for. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have dictionary or array literals. Instead we have interfaces,  `java.util.Map` and `java.util.List` in the Collections API. These have several implementations including `java.util.HashMap` and `java.util.ArrayList`. You can combine these in any way you want. Creating a list of maps can unfortunately become quite verbose since you have to call the appropriate methods to add elements to these data structures. I suggest that you read about the Collections API to learn about all of the data structures that are available in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Import utility:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

And then you can use `Map`. The first line declares an empty variable with the type of `HashMap` and the two next lines add data into it.

```
Map vehicles = new HashMap();
vehicles.put("BMW", 5);
vehicles.put("Mercedes", 3);
```

As @Code-Apprentice mentioned. You need to import the required utility.

Comment: `You need to import the required utility` You may as well mention what it is, and put the whole import line in for convenient copying.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the review. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no literal Dictionary in Java, the combination you're looking for is a `List<Map<String, String>>`  Both `List` and `Map` are interfaces, so they can't be directly instantiated.  In your case, the concrete classes for those are varied, but either `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` for `List` and `HashMap` for `Map`.

You can get something vaguely similar with anonymous classes:

```
List<Map<String, String>> myDict = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>() {{
    add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("title", "some title");
    }});
}}
```