# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() takes an array of Map<String,Object>, how do I instantiate the parameters array so that I don't get warnings?

Tags: java, arrays, spring-batch

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() takes a `Map<String,Object>[]` for the list of parameters.  I can't figure out how to instantiate the array in a way that doesn't get flagged with a "generic instantiation" error, or an "unchecked assignment" warning.  I really wish Spring accepted a List of Maps instead of an array.

Yes I've read: [How does one instantiate an array of maps in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493162/how-does-one-instantiate-an-array-of-maps-in-java?rq=1)

However, I don't control the spring-batch NamedParameterJdbcTemplate interface, so I can't change the signature of the batchUpdate() method.

I have a `List<Map<String,Object>>` named params.

I have tried the following:

```java
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
    sql,
    params.toArray(new Map<String,Object[0]) //generic instantiation error
); 

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
    sql,
    params.toArray(new Map[0]) //unchecked assignment warning
);
```

Full code:

```java
class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MyRecord> {
   @Autowired
   private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

   public void write(List<? extends MyRecord> items) {
      String sql = MyRecord.UPDATE_SQL;
      List<Map<String,Object>> params 
      = items.stream()
             .map(record->new MapBuilder<String,Object>()
                   .put("param1",record.getField1())
                   .put("param2",record.getField2())
                   .build())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
      namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
          sql,
          params.toArray(new Map<String,Object>[0]) //generic instantiation error
      );
      namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
          sql,
          params.toArray(new Map[0]) //unchecked assignment warning.
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, you cannot create an array of `Map<String, Object>`.

REF: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

So you create a `Map[]` then cast it to `Map<String, Object>[]` with the "unchecked cast" warning. Such a warning is suppressible. JDK EXAMPLE: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk14/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Map.java#L1682:L1689

```
  namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, toArray(params));


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static Map<String, ?>[] toArray(List<Map<String, ?>> params) {
    return params.toArray(new Map[0]);
}
```

---

NOTE: in your "Full code" example there is no need in collecting to an intermediate List. You can directly allocate the stream to an array. Unfortunately, the parameterless version of Stream's `toArray()` is still not generic. So you, again, have to use an overloaded `toArray(n->new Map[n])` version with the unavoidable, but suppressible warning:

```
  Map<String,?>[] params = items.stream()
      .map(record -> Map.of(
          "param1",record.getField1(),
          "param2",record.getField2()))
      .toArray(this::newArray);


  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private Map<String,?>[] newArray(int n) {
    return new Map[n];
  }
```