# Spring Boot REST to read JSON array payload

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have this PostMapping method

```
@PostMapping("/offreStage/{id}/users")
public ResponseEntity<?> addAuthorizedStudents(@PathVariable Long id,
                                               @RequestBody Map<String, String> students) {
    return service.addAuthorizedStudentsToOffer(id, students);
}
```

and I use the following JSON payload to make my post request:

```
[
    {
        "value": 15,
        "label": "student2@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "value": 14,
        "label": "student21@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

This returns the following:

> "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
>   `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception
>   is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY
>   token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body sent does not match with the one in the function.

More precisely, this is your map :

```
  {
        "value": 15,
        "label": "student2@gmail.com"
  }
```

You need a list of map, so it won't work. So it should be this : `List<Map<String, String>>` in the function.
Or better, use a collection ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493162/how-does-one-instantiate-an-array-of-maps-in-java)).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because of the way you are sending the JSON. In your example, you are essentially sending an Array of maps as Json and expecting Spring to convert it into a Map. In your JS convert the structure to a single map or you could use an object in your back end to map the data in the json accordingly like:

```
[
    {
        "value": 15,
        "label": "student2@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "value": 14,
        "label": "student21@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

and then you could use your controller like :

```
@PostMapping("/offreStage/{id}/users")
public ResponseEntity<?> addAuthorizedStudents(@PathVariable Long id,
                                               @RequestBody List<ObjectClass> students) {
    return service.addAuthorizedStudentsToOffer(id, students);
}
```

and your object class could be like :

```
public class ObjectClass {
String value;
String label;
//getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map is for key value pairs, you have list of key value pairs.

Change `Map<String, String>` to `List<Map<String, String>>`